# random result from mysql every refresh (f5)

Tags: php, random

Each time user enter's website get random information/text from mysql.
Question: How to make sure every time user refresh page she/he get difirrent information no the same viewed before?

First idea camed to my mind:

1. User enter's website, he/she get information which has `$id= '123';`
2. That id we store in session
3. User again refresh page and new if statment executed:

```php
if ($id == $random_id_from_mysql) {
    //select new id from mysql, because it's the same, viewed before
} else {
    //show new information and store $id in session for feature usage
}
```

Any new method available for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
session_start();

// If a value already exists in $_SESSION, it will be used.
// Otherwise, NULL
$prev_rand = isset($_SESSION['prev_rand']) ? $_SESSION['prev_rand'] : NULL;

// Query for a random record that isn't equal to the previous one 
// (or isn't NULL if no previous one exists)
// using RAND() and LIMIT 1
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, col1 FROM tbl WHERE id <> '$prev_rand' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

// Store the new rand value into session
$_SESSION['prev_rand'] = $row['id'];
```

Comment: Instead of a session, a get parameter and a redirect could be used. Or just a cookie.

Comment: Yes, a `$_GET` or `$_COOKIE` would work, but `$_SESSION` is more tamper-proof it it matters.

Comment: True, my comment was more meant as some alternative ways. The principle is exactly the same as in your answer, it's only some other form of *session*.

Comment: $prev_rand = isset($_SESSION['prev_rand']) ? $_SESSION['prev_rand'] : NULL; I think this correct, because your's doesn't work...

Comment: @ZeroSuf3r Yes, sorry for the typo. In my defense, a baby was (and still is) climbing on me as I type.

Comment: @ZeroSuf3r Be careful with ORDER BY RAND(). It's known to be less than optimal in MySQL especially when table sizes get big. Here's an article with some other ways to do it: http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/